# Summary column on EF

Tags: entity-framework, aggregate-functions, aggregate, summary

Is it possible to add summary properties(no database column) according LINQ from another property(column) in EF generated class from database and this property don't update(delete or remove from class) when update model from database(because this property(cloumn) is not on database)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Classed generated by Entity Framework as an Entitied are always marked `partial`. It lets you extend the functionality with your own properties or method.

Let say your entity class is named `Post`. You can extend it with code like that:

```
public partial class Post
{
    public int Average
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Items.Average();
        }
    }
}
```

Because it's not a part of designer-generated file it won't be overwritten when it's regenerated. However, there is one requirement to make it work: your custom part of `Post` class has to be in exactly the same namespace as code generated by EF.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `[NotMapped]` attribute on a property in a `partial class`. This will be ignored by Entity Framework.

```
public partial class EntityName
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int CalculatedProperty
    { 
        get 
        {
            return Numbers.Sum();
        }
    }
}
```